# How to extract binary data appended to a png file?

Tags: python, awk, command-line, png

It seems that if I append binary data to the end of a png file, the png file is still viewable. So the png file is still a valid file. Is there a way to automatically extract such trailing data from a png file whose original file size is not recorded?

Comment: I have no idea how to do so on the command line (and you may want to ask on superuser.com, since this is a request for a tool rather than a specific programming problem) but the specification is [detailed enough](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#5DataRep).

Comment: Is there a way to migrate the question to superuser?

Comment: It's faster if you just delete it here and post a-new over there.

Comment: I don't understand from the spec how to determine how many chunks there are or how to determine the original file size. Could you show me where it says this info?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many chunks there are; "IEND [...] Shall be last" (Table 5.3).  The size of each chunk is defined in itself.

Answer (score 7):

PNGs end with an "IEND" chunk.  The last 12 bytes always look the same.  So you could perhaps use:

```
dd if=appended.png of=extracted.png bs=1 count=$((($(od -t x1 appended.png | awk '{$1=""}1' | tr -d \\n | sed "s/00 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82/XMATCHX/" | tr X \\n  | grep -b MATCH | cut -f1 -d:)-2)/3+12))
```

The above is a little longer than it needs be to work on macos, which handles `grep -b` differently than GNU grep.

The gist of it is:

- Use dd to extract count bytes from the beginning of the `appended.png`
- Determine the count by:

  - convert file to hex string of space separated bytes on one line using od/awk/tr
  - search for IEND pattern and replace with `MATCH` using sed/tr
  - get offset of MATCH using `grep -b` and `cut`
  - calc actual file length (subtract extra space/CR, divide by 3 hex chars/space per byte, add 12 for IEND len)

Note: it is unlikely, if not impossible, that the 12 byte IEND chunk can occur within the PNG, but the above does not check for it.

That was a fun coronaviral exercise - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can run `pngcheck -v YOURFILE.png` and it will tell you if there are extra bytes at the end and exit with error status `2`.

It will also tell you where the actual end-of-file is:

```
# Generate legitimate PNG with ImageMagick
convert -size 300x400 gradient:yellow-red orig.png

# Check its size
ls -l orig.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  2509  3 May 17:47 orig.png

# Check it with `pngcheck` - exit status = 0, i.e. all ok
    File: orig.png (2509 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    300 x 400 image, 48-bit RGB, non-interlaced
  chunk gAMA at offset 0x00025, length 4: 0.45455
  chunk cHRM at offset 0x00035, length 32
    White x = 0.3127 y = 0.329,  Red x = 0.64 y = 0.33
    Green x = 0.3 y = 0.6,  Blue x = 0.15 y = 0.06
  chunk bKGD at offset 0x00061, length 6
    red = 0xffff, green = 0xffff, blue = 0xffff
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00073, length 2276
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, maximum compression
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x00963, length 37, keyword: date:create
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x00994, length 37, keyword: date:modify
  chunk IEND at offset 0x009c5, length 0
No errors detected in orig.png (8 chunks, 99.7% compression).
```

Now append some rubbish to the end:

```
ls -l >> orig.png

# Check the size again
ls -l orig.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  8398  3 May 17:53 orig.png

# And check again - exit status =2
pngcheck -v orig.png
File: orig.png (8398 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    300 x 400 image, 48-bit RGB, non-interlaced
  chunk gAMA at offset 0x00025, length 4: 0.45455
  chunk cHRM at offset 0x00035, length 32
    White x = 0.3127 y = 0.329,  Red x = 0.64 y = 0.33
    Green x = 0.3 y = 0.6,  Blue x = 0.15 y = 0.06
  chunk bKGD at offset 0x00061, length 6
    red = 0xffff, green = 0xffff, blue = 0xffff
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00073, length 2276
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, maximum compression
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x00963, length 37, keyword: date:create
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x00994, length 37, keyword: date:modify
  chunk IEND at offset 0x009c5, length 0
  additional data after IEND chunk
ERRORS DETECTED in orig.png
```

It also tells you where the real end of the file is in the 3rd to last line, i.e. at 0x009c5. You will need to add 8 to that to allow for the size of the IEND itself.

---

By the way, if on macOS, you can install `pngcheck` with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install pngcheck
```